# How does acid damage skin?

Tags: acid-base, ph

As I understand it, acids are substances which have a high concentration of H+ ion which makes acid an acid. When interacting with our skin, acid can damage it. How does this concentration of protons cause damage to skin?

Comment: Those protons don't simply sit around doing nothing. They tend to bind to/attack  the polymers (keratin and such) that make up your skin and form newer, smaller molecules; i.e- it breaks down the polymers that constitute your skin. The stronger the acid is, the higher the concentration of protons in it, and hence, greater the tendency/chances of them binding to your skin.

Comment: Also there is a [relay proton distribution mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grotthuss_mechanism) which accelerates the impact pointed out by @paracetamol.

Comment: Not only high pH but also concentration of anions is dangerous.

Comment: @Mithoron High pH is indeed dangerous (dissolves the skin tissue), but acids have low pH. And skin is fairly resistant even to strong acids. The problem are indeed the anions (e.g. the notorious fluoride) and undissociated acids that diffuse through the skin.

Comment: In addition, the corrosive (to be taken in a broad sense, here) property of many acid does not result from - or not only from - their ability to donate protons but from their chemistry as a whole . They can dehydrate and oxidize almost everything in the tissues, (eg H2SO4), undergo specific reaction (eg HNO3 reacts with proteins to give yellow xanthoproteins), etc.

Comment: Also I would like to note that, as being the question somehow related to safety, one can finally speak of acid as proton donors without starting unnecessary wrong cascade of comments like "it is wrong" or "you refer to centuries year old theory now dismissed". Acid did are doing and will burn the skin. As they were are and always will be donating protons. Of course if they have at least one :)